# Feature Class Iterator in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, interpolation

I am hoping to run a simple Iterator operation in ModelBuilder, but everything I attempt is not producing the right results.

I have a Geodatabase with many point files in it. I want to run and Inverse Distance Weighted interpolation on each one.

The only iterator that will allow me to connect the to as an input feature is Feature Class, however this results in only one raster being output.

Other Iterators, such as Datasets and Files, will not give me the "Input Feature" option when I try to connect it.

Please let me know if you can identify what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Keep using the 'Iterate Feature Classes' iterator as this is the correct one to use. Ensure you use [in-line variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000060000000) when naming the output from the IDW tool. If you don't, each time the tool is ran it will use the same output path/name and overwrite the previous output.

See my example below:

[image]